# How to render emojis rightly in flutter dynamically?

Tags: flutter, django-rest-framework, emoji

How to render emojis in dynamic text correctly in flutter?
I am taking input from the user which can have emojis and I am storing it on the server.
When I view the data on the server, it looks fine(with emojis).
But when I decode the data in my app from json, it shows invalid characters.

I am decoding the data simply using

```
postDetailText = serverData['Post']['text'];
```

I am not sure if there are any other methods to store data efficiently.

Comment: I would take a closer look at your encoding

Comment: I am converting a NotusDocument to HTML and then I am encoding it using json.encode(text)